# Going for a party/to a party

Tags: prepositional-phrases, phrase-choice

> 1. Just as I was entering the room, the family was going **for a party**.
> 2. Just as I was entering the room, the family was going **to the party**.

Out of the two which one is correct and by which grammatical rule?

Comment: What is it you are trying to say?  That upon entering you found that the family were all headed out to go to a party?  That upon entering you found the family all pretending to be at a party?  That upon entering you found that the family was currently having a party in the room?  And you should decide whether it's ***a*** or ***the***.  Did you know about this party before you entered the room?

Comment: @Jim  This is just a sentence given in my exam under sentence improvement section.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+for+a+party%2Cgo+to+a+party&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20for%20a%20party%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20to%20a%20party%3B%2Cc0

Comment: There's a difference between going for **a** party and **the** party. I have kept as it is. Seema, has this happened by mistake or you want to know that difference as well?

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine a situation in which you would say someone is going **for a party**. In English we invariably say that **we're** (or **someone's**) **going to a party**. There might be unique circumstances in which you'd use that phrasing, but they're rare.

Examples:

We got dressed up to go out to a party.

They'd spent a lot of time preparing to go to the party.

Just as I was entering the room, the family was going to the party. (Though this one sounds slightly unnatural out of context.)